# Strange character showing up in older firefox

Tags: html, firefox, ascii

For some reason this () character shows up in Firefox 10 randomly throughout my site, but does not appear in other browsers.  I'm not sure if Stack Overflow will render it, so I'm attaching a screenshot of one area this occurs. It Looks like ASCII encoding...Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: If i paste it into google, it renders a question mark....but there are no question marks in the HTML where these are showing up.

Comment: How is this html's source created? Was it just pasted from somewhere, like text editor or something?

Comment: The same character shows on this page with some information: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0003/index.htm

Comment: no the source is created from a php file, with standard html. The only reason I am using php is so I can use includes

Comment: For instance, the HTML which creates the above text is:<blockquote>"Foundation Source allows us to focus on key client issues as a financial advisor. They have far exceeded our expectations. They are responsive and take all the problems and difficulties out of administering a foundation."<cite>Julia M. Beisel V.P. Private Wealth, Atlantic Trust Private Wealth Management</cite></blockquote>

Comment: Could you check this file's contents with some hex editor?

Comment: I did it here:  http://www.edithex.com/  but I dont understand the results...

Comment: maybe you have a browser add-on that's trying to change content with some links, but it's failing miserably (for example, Skype would replace phone numbers it finds with links to calls, etc)

Comment: Don't copy all the string - just `on key` part would suffice. i.e., when there's `\U0003` character present.

Comment: Ahhh, if I retype all of the text, it works fine. I suppose I copy pasted from a website, which also stored these hex codes. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction raina77ow, if you post an answer Ill accept.

Comment: Ok, and thanks for your active participation: it's too often that posters are actually the last people interested in solving their problem. You're an exception to that sad trend. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol in question is `Unicode Character 'END OF TEXT' (U+0003)`, and looks like it was inserted into the original text by some editor or something - and it was successfully copied into your HTML files. ) Just find and replace them all with fire, I say!